# JS drag and drop with dynamically created events

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a language card game and I have divs that are created dynamically. I want to be able to drag the div into another div. I have followed a couple tutorials and have ended with something like this.

My problem is, I can drag the div, but I can't drop it in the box... I'm not too sure why and how I should fix it. If anyone could help, I would really appreciate it.

```js
var nounCards = ["a", "b", "c"];
var verbCards = ["1", "2", "3"];

var deck = new Array();
var deck2 = new Array();
var hand = new Array();

function getDeck() {
  var deck = new Array();
  for (var x = 0; x < nounCards.length; x++) {
    var nounCard = {
      Value: nounCards[x][0]
    };
    deck.push(nounCard);
  }
  return deck;
}

function getDeck2() {
  var deck2 = new Array();
  for (var x = 0; x < verbCards.length; x++) {
    var verbCard = {
      Value: verbCards[x]
    };
    deck2.push(verbCard);
  }
  return deck2;
}

function getHand() {
  var hand = new Array();
  for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
    var verbCard = {
      Value: verbCards[x]
    };
    hand.push(verbCard);
  }
  for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
    var nounCard = {
      Value: nounCards[x][0]
    };
    hand.push(nounCard);
  }
  return hand;
}

function shuffle() {
  // for 1000 turns
  // switch the values of two random cards
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var location1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * deck.length));
    var location2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * deck.length));
    var tmp = deck[location1];

    deck[location1] = deck[location2];
    deck[location2] = tmp;

    var location1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * deck2.length));
    var location2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * deck2.length));
    var tmp = deck2[location1];

    deck2[location1] = deck2[location2];
    deck2[location2] = tmp;
  }

  renderDeck();
  renderDeck2();
  renderHand();

}

function renderDeck() {
  document.getElementById('deck').innerHTML = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
    var card = document.createElement("div");
    var value = document.createElement("div");
    card.className = "card";
    value.className = "value";

    value.innerHTML = deck[i].Value;
    card.appendChild(value);

    document.getElementById("deck").appendChild(card);
  }
}

function renderDeck2() {
  document.getElementById('deck2').innerHTML = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < deck2.length; i++) {
    var card = document.createElement("div");
    var value = document.createElement("div");
    card.className = "card";
    value.className = "value";

    value.innerHTML = deck2[i].Value;
    card.appendChild(value);

    document.getElementById("deck2").appendChild(card);
  }
}

function renderHand() {
  document.getElementById('hand').innerHTML = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < hand.length; i++) {
    //creating the actual card and making it a draggable element
    var card = document.createElement("div");
    card.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
    card.setAttribute("ondragstart", "onDragStart(event);");

    //setting the value or the "words" as a div
    var value = document.createElement("div");

    card.className = "card";
    value.className = "value";

    value.innerHTML = hand[i].Value;
    card.appendChild(value);


    //putting the card in the div
    document.getElementById("hand").appendChild(card);
  }
}


function onDragStart(event) {
  event
    .dataTransfer
    .setData('text/plain', event.target.id);

  event
    .currentTarget
    .style
    .backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
}

function onDragOver(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

function onDrop(event) {
  const id = event
    .dataTransfer
    .getData('text');

  const draggableElement = document.getElementById(id);

  const dropzone = event.target;
  dropzone.appendChild(draggableElement);

  event
    .dataTransfer
    .clearData();
}

function load() {
  deck = getDeck();
  deck2 = getDeck2();
  hand = getHand();
  shuffle();

}
window.onload = load;
```

```css
.deck {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #DADADA;
  border: solid 2px black;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.card {
  border: solid 1px #808080;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  margin: 3px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 90px;
}

.btn {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.card .value {
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 3px;
  border: dotted #000;
  border-width: medium;
}

.box.nouns {
  background-color: grey;
}

.playingSpace {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="deck"></div>
<div id="deck2"></div>

<div class="playingSpace">
  <div class="box" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event);"></div>

  <h2>Your cards</h2>

  <div id="hand" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event);"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you give me more details on which div you are trying to drag to which div? if you can even say with the label and the id of them would be great. the error that I'm getting is in appending to a child

Comment: I'm trying to move the card div from the renderHand() method. I haven't set an id though... Could that be why there are issues? I'm trying to drag that div into the playingSpace div. Thank you